# Trying to remove white space between the navigation bar and the body of the text

Tags: css, whitespace

For the below URL, I have whitespace between my nav bar and the main content. How do I remove this? I have been playing around with the CSS but no luck.

https://www.cleaningdorset.co.uk/end-of-tenancy/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.entry-content` has both `margin: 42px 0;` and `margin: 35px 0;` while #content.site-content got a `padding: 35px 0;`

Remove those and the white gap will disappear.

---

I would also look through every element on the page, if I were you, and remove any necessary CSS code. I mean, #content.site-content is an absolute element with clear-fix, for no apparent reason.